# Load a PNG resource into a CBitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, png

How do I load a png resource into a `CBitMap`? When I try this it doesn't seem to work:

```
CImage image;
image.LoadFromResource(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), IDB_PNG1);
bitmap.Attach(image.Detach());
```

It gives me an error resource type not found. Is there any other way to load a PNG resource?

Comment: Is the error in LoadFromResource or in Attach?

Answer (score 19):

If you are using VS2008 or newer (MFC Feature Pack) you can use `CPngImage` which derives from `CBitmap` and is contained in `<afxtoolbarimages.h>`. `CPngImage` is an [internal class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/internal-classes?view=vs-2019):

> The following classes are used internally in MFC. For completeness, this section describes these internal classes, but they are not intended to be used directly in your code.

If you want to use `CPngImage` you need to use the resource type `"PNG"`:

> ```
> #define AFX_PNG_RESOURCE_TYPE  _T("PNG")
> ```

#### Example usage

```
CPngImage image;
image.Load(IDB_PNG1, nullptr);
bitmap.Attach(image.Detach());
```

Comment: Good find! I wish it was better documented, I really could've used this for years :(

Answer (score 6):

`LoadFromResource` uses `LoadImage` internally, it doesn't support PNG last time I tried, despite what the documentation says. You can link with `CxImage` (look on CodeProject) but it's a lot of work for little real benefit.

What I did in the end was forget about PNG, use `AlphaConv` to convert PNG's into 32-bit Windows bitmaps and use `CImage` with those. Additional advantage is that you can use them with `CBitmapButton` etc. in MFC without any transformations.

Another way to hack around it is to extract the resource contents to a temporary file, then use `CImage::Load` to read it from there. If I'd catch you doing that in one of my code bases I'd punch you in the face though ;)

Comment: +1 for a developer who is really going to defend his code base

Answer (score 3):

If you do not really need a `CBitmap`, but only an handle this may useful for you.

Or if you can get a `CBitmap` from the `HBITMAP` this function returns it is also good.

I use this on a commercial application and it works.

```
// Based on afxbutton.cpp's static function ButtonLoadBitmap
HBITMAP __stdcall ButtonLoadBitmap(UINT uiBmpResId)
{
    if (uiBmpResId == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    LPCTSTR lpszResourceName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(uiBmpResId);
    ENSURE(lpszResourceName != NULL);

    HBITMAP hbmp = NULL;

    // Try to load PNG image first:
    CPngImage pngImage;
    if (pngImage.Load(lpszResourceName))
    {
        hbmp = (HBITMAP) pngImage.Detach();
    }
    else
    {
        HINSTANCE hinstRes = AfxFindResourceHandle(lpszResourceName, RT_BITMAP);
        if (hinstRes == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }

        UINT uiLoadImageFlags = LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS;

        hbmp = (HBITMAP) ::LoadImage(hinstRes, lpszResourceName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, uiLoadImageFlags);
    }

    return hbmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like `CxImage` (http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm) to do all the heavy lifting for you.  The code becomes as simple as :-

```
CxImage image;
if (image.LoadResource(<resource_instance_handle>, <resource_id>, CXIMAGETYPE_PNG))
{
    HBITMAP hbmp = image.CreateHBITMAP();
    ... do something with hbmp ...
}
```

(note that I'm writing this code from memory -- you may need to tweak it slightly to get it to work!)

I use `CxImage` a lot for the graphics in my programs and it simplifies things tremendously.