# How to load a png resource into picture control on a dialog box?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, png

I tried the following code on OnInitDialog() but nothing was shown.

```
m_staticLogo.SetBitmap(::LoadBitmap(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_LOGO)));
```

where `m_staticLogo` is the static picture control and `IDB_LOGO` is the resource ID of the png file.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005685/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you’ve discovered, `::LoadBitmap` (and the newer `::LoadImage`) only deal with `.bmp`s. By far the easiest solution is to convert your image to a `.bmp`.

If the image has transparency, it can be converted into a 32-bit ARGB bitmap (here is a tool called [AlphaConv](http://www.najmanowicz.com/temp/AlphaConv.zip) that can convert it). Then load the image using the `CImage` class `LoadFromResource` method. Pass the `CImage` to `m_staticLogo.SetBitmap()`.

But if you *really* need it to be a `.png`, it can be done.

**Method 1 (the easier way):** Load the `.png` from a file using `CImage::Load`. Pass the `CImage` to `m_staticLogo.SetBitmap()`.

**Method 2 (the harder way):** Load the `.png` from a resource by loading the resource into a COM `IStream` and using `CImage::Load`. (NOTE: `CImage::LoadFromResource` looks tempting but will not work with a `.png` graphic). To get the resource into a COM `IStream`, see [this Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/cgdiplusbitmap.aspx). Note the article works with `Gdiplus::Bitmap` but the key part is how to create the `IStream`, which you should be able to adapt for `CImage`. Finally, pass the `CImage` to `m_staticLogo.SetBitmap()`.

**Edit:** Updated to use `CImage`, which is easier than `Gdiplus::Bitmap`.

Comment: I converted the png file to bmp but the problem is that the background of the image is not transparent anymore after the conversion. Is there any way to convert and yet still preserve the transparent background?

Comment: Method 1 works but I would prefer to have the graphic in the resource file. Method 2 is too difficult for me.

Comment: You can preserve transparency by converting the `.png` to a 32-bit “ARGB” `.bmp`. Standard tools like Paint.NET will not do this. I’ve updated the article with a tool that works. It may look strange when viewed in Visual Studio but renders fine. This works well against one-color backgrounds. It won’t work if you have a complex background like a photo.

Comment: Method 1: I am using `CPngImage` and loading from resources. Works great. But, does the PNG need to be a member variable of my dialog, or can I declare it in `OnInitDialog` when I am setting up the picture control?

Answer (score 5):

For those, who need quick solution, here is a way to load png file from resources using GDI+ (original answer for standard GDI from here - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/377803/How-to-load-PNG-images-in-mfc):

```
bool GdiPlusUtils::LoadBitmapFromPNG(UINT uResourceID, 
    Bitmap** ppBitmapOut, HINSTANCE hInstance /*= NULL*/)
{
    bool bRet = false;

    if (!hInstance)
        hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();

    HRSRC hResourceHandle = ::FindResource(
        hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(uResourceID), L"PNG");
    if (0 == hResourceHandle)
    {
        return bRet;
    }

    DWORD nImageSize = ::SizeofResource(hInstance, hResourceHandle);
    if (0 == nImageSize)
    {
        return bRet;
    }

    HGLOBAL hResourceInstance = ::LoadResource(hInstance, hResourceHandle);
    if (0 == hResourceInstance)
    {
        return bRet;
    }

    const void* pResourceData = ::LockResource(hResourceInstance);
    if (0 == pResourceData)
    {
        FreeResource(hResourceInstance);
        return bRet;
    }

    HGLOBAL hBuffer = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, nImageSize);
    if (0 == hBuffer)
    {
        FreeResource(hResourceInstance);
        return bRet;
    }

    void* pBuffer = ::GlobalLock(hBuffer);
    if (0 != pBuffer)
    {
        CopyMemory(pBuffer, pResourceData, nImageSize);
        IStream* pStream = 0;
        if (S_OK == ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hBuffer, FALSE, &pStream))
        {
            *ppBitmapOut = new Bitmap(pStream);
            pStream->Release();
            bRet = true;
        }
        ::GlobalUnlock(hBuffer);
    }
    ::GlobalFree(hBuffer);

    UnlockResource(hResourceInstance);
    FreeResource(hResourceInstance);

    return bRet;
}
```

You can add png file as resource using Add Resource command and in the panel choose Import.

Comment: Can you give an example of the proper way of calling LoadBitmapFromPNG() ?

Comment: It's easy, just use:

Bitmap* pBitmap = 0;
LoadBitmapFromPNG(IDB_PNG_YOUR_RESOURCE_ID, &pBitmap);

where Bitmap* is GDI+ bitmap class and IDB_PNG_YOUR_RESOURCE_ID is ID of your resource pointing to bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap and icon it supports. Not sure about png.
Alternately, May be you can try the following.

1. open png in MS Paint or some other viewer.
2. Then copy the image portion from that.
3. Create a resource in MFC resource.
4. Paste the copied image to newly created resource.
5. Use new resource id in LoadBitmap.

Answer (score -1):

If you are converting .png image file to .bmp format, you can end up with image clarity. So, catch WM_PAINT message in dialog box class and use

Graphics::DrawImage method

To obtain this method link your project with gdiplus.lib library.