# What's wrong with my code to load a png to a mfc static picture control?

Tags: mfc

```
CImage image;
    image.Load(L"e:\\final.png");  
    int width = image.GetWidth();
    int height  = image.GetHeight();
    SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);

    HBITMAP hBmp = image.Detach();  
    CStatic* pWnd = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC); 
    pWnd->SetBitmap(hBmp);  
    pWnd->SetWindowPos(NULL,   0,   0,   width, height, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Add above code into the mfc-generated dialog's initdialog routine. But the png does not show.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490661/how-to-load-png-jpeg-images-using-mfc and this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988484/mfc-is-there-any-way-to-load-a-png-resource-into-picture-control-on-a-dialog-b

Comment: why do you cast from CWnd* to CStatic?? have created a one instance of CStatic before?? so it wiil return it as CWnd* ? or you force it to become CStatic*? I think this is not recommended use new casting ways (dynamic_cast, static_cast, reinterpret_cast), look for full example this may lead you to the solution as i think it is style issue has you used those styles SS_BITMAP|SS_CENTERIMAGE, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b7w5x74z.aspx

Comment: @Ahmedsafan: it is because i do not set bitmap style to the control. thx for your answer. plz post it as answer, so i could choose it.

Comment: use a "real" ID for the control instead of `IDC_STATIC`

Comment: @Jichao: I have added it as an answer, and waiting for you to mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment and was reported by @Jichao that was correct solution.

Look for full example this may lead you to the solution as I think it is window style issue. You should include the styles of `SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE` in the static control resource definition.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b7w5x74z.aspx

> **Remarks**
>
> The bitmap will be automatically drawn in the static control. By
>   default, it will be drawn in the upper-left corner and the static
>   control will be resized to the size of the bitmap.
>
> You can use various window and static control styles, including these:
>
> `SS_BITMAP` Use this style always for bitmaps.
>
> `SS_CENTERIMAGE` Use to center the image in the static control. If the
>   image is larger than the static control, it will be clipped. If it is
>   smaller than the static control, the empty space around the image will
>   be filled by the color of the pixel in the upper left corner of the
>   bitmap.