# Can't use a transparent BMP with MFC Button control

Tags: mfc, ide, imagebutton, visual-studio-2017

I am really confused here ...

I am trying to add a **MFC Button control** onto my dialog in the IDE.

I want it to just show a BMP file. I have another already on the dialog that shows with a **transparent** background.

This is the image for the good button:

[image: Good Transparency]

This is the other button image I downloaded. But it is PNG:

[image: New image PNG]

I have tried to convert it so that it is 32 bit BMP so that it is transparent:

[image: New image BMP]

But it is failing. It shows with a black background:

[image: Results]

You can see on that screenshot that the lower image shows OK. But not the new one. How do I fix this image file?

Update:

I used a different image in the end for the question mark. But for others I ended up using PNG and manually using the load method as outlined below:

[image]

Comment: For some reason the images are not showing correctly in the question.

Comment: Has it been saved correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29585717/59303

Comment: How did you convert the png to bmp ? It doesn't work with Paint. But it does with Gimp.

Comment: I used paint. I will try Gimp. Anything else I need to know to make work? Just save PNG as BMP? Will try tonight

Comment: I remember I had to downgrade Gimp to 2.6 version because newer versions saved the BMP file differently!

Comment: @sergiol Good to know, I'm using 2.6.12 and it works fine. Just amazing that BMP supports transparency but MSPaint doesn't.

Comment: You don't need to convert the image to a BMP in order to use it on the dialog.  I've done what you've asked and used the PNG image as is.

Comment: I was meaning 2.6.0!

Comment: @rrirower How? When I select a MFCButton and set the type it must be Bitmap or Icon and it only lists my Bitmaps and none of my PNG resources.

Comment: You can use GDI+ and the PNG image to craft your own Button class.  That would negate the need to convert the image to a BMP and you would not need to use CMFCButton.

Comment: rrirower That may be, but the point it, I should be able to do it. I have another MFC Button on the same dialogue with a transparent BMP. I am struggling with GIMP. @sergiol Can you guys confirm the advanced settings to use? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have that computer anymore, but one thing I remember that made confusion was the format. Don't take my advice for sure, but if I recall it correctly, on the https://hostr.co/files/QCtMjXp/Export%20Image%20as%20BMP.png dialog I had to select `A8 R8 G8 B8` on the `32 bit` section.

Comment: BTW, once ago I did http://stackoverflow.com/a/22875225/383779 to make use of images on `CMFCButton` controls.

Comment: I confirmed now I used the code I linked on my previous comment to load PNG images using `HBITMAP hbmp;`      `hbmp =::MyButtonLoadBitmap(IDB_OK);`      `m_btnOK.SetBitmap(hbmp);`

Comment: BTW, You may have to Pre-Multiply alpha values because I don't know if it uses the `AlphaBlend ` function on behind. So refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and read CAREFULLY the `AlphaFormat`parameter explanation. So, I will put code on next comment as it does not fit here.

Comment: `for (int y=0; y<bmInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight; ++y)`
    `{`
        `BYTE pPixel= (BYTE ) lpDIBBits + bmInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth  4  y;`
        `for (int x=0; x<bmInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth ; ++x)`
        `{`
            `pPixel[0]= pPixel[0]*pPixel[3]/255;`
            `pPixel[1]= pPixel[1]*pPixel[3]/255;`
            `pPixel[2]= pPixel[2]*pPixel[3]/255;`
            `pPixel+= 4;`
        `}`
    `}`

Comment: Or you will have to do http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?420631-setting-CImage-alpha-values&p=1560260#post1560260 which does the pre-multiplication, but also adds 127. I did not fully understood why the + 127 , but this post was the "savior of the motherland" for me when I had a problem doing `AlphaBlend` of PNG images where image lines where appearing incorrectly.

Comment: @sergiol I used the `MyButtonLoadBitmap` ... :)

Comment: Can you post here please a capture to see if your image is presenting well itself?

Comment: @sergiol I tried another image and for some reason it shows a black edge to the image when the source does not have it. I see your comments about AlphaFormat but they are a bit over my head.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: See my question and my own answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183799/mfc-cimage-alpha-blending-gone-wrong