# MFC CImage alpha blending gone wrong

Tags: image, visual-c++, mfc, png, alphablending

I have to present images on a picture control that are a composition of two PNG files, where the top image has transparent pixels on certain positions.

The result should of plotter.png

[image]

with bar.png

[image]

overlapped on its top appears as (Notice the strange white contours on the bar):

[image]

but it should be:

[image]

The code I made for it is simple as

```
    CImage image;
    if (FAILED(image.Load(L"plotter.png")))
        return false;

    CImage imageBar;
    if (FAILED(imageBar.Load(L"bar.png")))
        return false;

    imageBar.AlphaBlend(image.GetDC(), CPoint());
    image.ReleaseDC();


    ((CStatic*)GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE))->SetBitmap(image);
```

I have read the MSDN documentation on [Alpha Blending a Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183353.aspx) and [BLENDFUNCTION structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183393) and did some experiments. A detail made me stare on the text I am quoting:

> This flag is set when the bitmap has an Alpha channel (that is,
>   per-pixel alpha). Note that the APIs use premultiplied alpha, which
>   means that the red, green and blue channel values in the bitmap must
>   be premultiplied with the alpha channel value. For example, if the
>   alpha channel value is x, the red, green and blue channels must be
>   multiplied by x and divided by 0xff prior to the call.

`Alphablend` uses **premultiplied alpha**, which means after loading I have to go to the bitmap and multiply every pixel by its own alpha. So I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageBar.GetWidth(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < imageBar.GetHeight(); j++)
    {
        BYTE* ptr = (BYTE*) imageBar.GetPixelAddress(i, j);
        ptr[0] = (ptr[0] * ptr[3]) / 255;
        ptr[1] = (ptr[1] * ptr[3]) / 255;
        ptr[2] = (ptr[2] * ptr[3]) / 255;
    }
}
```

before the `AlphaBlend`line and what I've got is still not satisfactory :(

So, how can I get a correctly composed image?

Comment: Make sure that your PNG files are 24-bit as 8-bit PNGs do not support transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days and night of desperation, I've finally found http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?420631-setting-CImage-alpha-values&p=1560260#post1560260 which a solution similar to what I've tried, but with the **addition of 127** to every pixel, which is a thing that worked but I've not understood at the time, nor I had made any effort to understand it yet. So before the `AlphaBlend` line now there is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageBar.GetWidth(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < imageBar.GetHeight(); j++)
    {
        BYTE* ptr = (BYTE*)imageBar.GetPixelAddress(i, j);
        ptr[0] = ((ptr[0] * ptr[3]) + 127) / 255;
        ptr[1] = ((ptr[1] * ptr[3]) + 127) / 255;
        ptr[2] = ((ptr[2] * ptr[3]) + 127) / 255;
    }
}
```

and now the displayed image is well composed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by setting `dwFlags = 0` while creating a background image.

```
background->Create(100, 100, 32, 0);
```