Problem using transparent PNGs for menu items in MFC
I was directed to an existing answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222653/2287576
But I am struggling to follow that code. This is what I have:
CPngImage png;
png.Load(IDB_PNG_MENU_REPORT, AfxGetResourceHandle());
m_bmp.Attach(png.Detach());

//CBitmap png = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(AfxGetResourceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG_MENU_REPORT),
//  IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

auto pMenu = GetMenu();
if (pMenu)
{
    pMenu->SetMenuItemBitmaps(ID_MANAGE_CONGREGATIONS_REPORT_VIEWER, MF_BYCOMMAND, &m_bmp, &m_bmp);
}

But this is the result I get:

I am not sure how to use the advertised code in the linked discussion.
My way does not work because the transparency in the PNG turns white.


Which image editor are you using for editing the PNGs? I would suggest one capable of working with layers, like Photoshop, Paintshop Pro or GIMP.

@ConstantineGeorgiou Paint appears to work just fine with transparent images. Have you tried using transparent PNG and done a quick test with my code?

Not really. The reason I'm asking is because of @IInspectable comment in the linked answer. GDI works with premultiplied alphas, therefore an easy fix is change the RGB value for all transparent pixels to black (easier done with a better image editor). I will post an answer. But what are you trying to do exactly? The SetMenuItemBitmaps() function is for replacing the default checked and unchecked bitmaps for menu items. Maybe you want to add icons to your menu items. In this case you should instead use the CMFCMenuBar class. This in not a Win32 feature, the icons are owner-drawn by MFC.

Transparency wasn't supported when Windows was first created, it was a relatively late addition.  So support is a bit sketchy in a lot of areas.

@ConstantineGeorgiou It looks like CMFCMenuBar is not designed for CDialog applications and I would have a lot of code-refactoring to do. So I won't go down that route.

See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183800/383779

Well, there are several posts about this in the forum, including some suggesting manipulating the bitmap. As @IInspectable pointed-out in your linked answer, GDI uses premultiplied alphas. Therefore an easy fix is to change all fully transparent pixels to black. You need an image editor supporting layers for this. The steps can be:

Add a black background layer (at the bottom of the stack).
On top of this add a gray layer - the application may work on a light or dark mode Windows machine, so this may be acceptable for both.
On top of this you have your image. Load the alpha and make it a mask for this layer.
Merge the gray and your image layers.
Create a copy of the alpha, and modify it so that black (ie (0,0,0)) pixels remain as they are and all others become white (255,255,255). Make this a mask for the merged layer. Then delete the copied/modified alpha.
Merge the black background and your new merged layer. Now you have a single RGB layer and an alpha channel (the original).
Save the file.

The steps above will make all transparent areas black, while the image (and I'm referring specifically to the transitional ones) would be merged with the gray background, attempting to preserve the "smoothing" effect, so no "jaggies" appear.
Try the PNG below. I have omitted the intermediate gray layer steps, because I couldn't do it, as I don't have the alpha.

A side-note, you don't need to copy the CPngImage image to a CBitmap variable, as CPngImage derives from CBitmap, you can pass CPngImage images to SetMenuItemBitmaps() directly.

Thanks for your answer. It feels like a lot of work for 70+ icons. I think I will stick with my current approach for now.
