# How to load a PNG from RESOURCES into a CImage

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

According to this documentation for [`LoadFromResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class#a-nameloadfromresourcea--cimageloadfromresource) it states:

> Loads an image from a **`BITMAP`** resource

So, I have this in my code:

```
rImage.LoadFromResource(AfxFindResourceHandle(), IDB_PNG1);
```

Doesn't work. I then realised I am using PNG files and not BMP files. I assume this is the reason the resources can't be found.

I have also tried using `AfxGetInstanceHandle()`. But that also doesn't work.

Thus, at the moment I am using external PNG files. It works fine. But is there **any** way to load a PNG from the resources into a `CImage`?

## Update

The comment provided to me was helpful.

It led me [here](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2011/08/04/display-images-as-you-type-in-cpp/). So, if I have this method:

```
IStream* CreateStreamOnResource(LPCTSTR lpName, LPCTSTR lpType)
{
    IStream * ipStream = NULL;

    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, lpName, lpType);
    if (hrsrc == NULL)
        goto Return;

    DWORD dwResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    HGLOBAL hglbImage = LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    if (hglbImage == NULL)
        goto Return;

    LPVOID pvSourceResourceData = LockResource(hglbImage);
    if (pvSourceResourceData == NULL)
        goto Return;

    HGLOBAL hgblResourceData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwResourceSize);
    if (hgblResourceData == NULL)
        goto Return;

    LPVOID pvResourceData = GlobalLock(hgblResourceData);

    if (pvResourceData == NULL)
        goto FreeData;

    CopyMemory(pvResourceData, pvSourceResourceData, dwResourceSize);

    GlobalUnlock(hgblResourceData);

    if (SUCCEEDED(CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hgblResourceData, TRUE, &ipStream)))
        goto Return;

FreeData:
    GlobalFree(hgblResourceData);

Return:
    return ipStream;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
rImage.Load(CreateStreamOnResource(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), _T("PNG")));
```

Works fine ... Thanks guys.

## Update:

Based on comment provided. This better now? I see no leaks:

```
IStream *pStream = CreateStreamOnResource(MAKEINTRESOURCE(uPNGResourceID), _T("PNG"));
if (pStream != nullptr)
{
    rImage.Load(pStream);
    rImage.SetHasAlphaChannel(true);
    pStream->Release();
}
```

Side note: Do I really need to call `SetHasAlphaChannel` if these are my own embedded resources and I **know** the are transparent 32 bit resources?

Comment: Related: [Load a png resource into a CBitMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005685/load-a-png-resource-into-a-cbitmap)

Comment: No. You have a memory leak. You have to call Release to the IStream interface. Or you use a CComPtr<IStream> as return value.

Comment: As I stated using CComPtr<IStream> would make it much easier... I assume that you just need to change the declaration to CComPtr<IStream> ipStream; And of course the return value. Than rImage.Load(CreateStreamOnResource(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), _T("PNG"))); would be possible.

Comment: I thought I had already mentioned that I made a change to call `Release`. But I take your point. Thanks.

Comment: Added a new text to my answer:
EDIT: Also the new MFC provides a `CPngBitmap` that allows to load a PNG file as a HBITMAP directly from a memory source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `AfxFindResource`
2. `LoadResource`
3. `GlobalAlloc`
4. `CopyMemory`
5. `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`
6. `CImage::Load(IStream*...)`

Or you write your own `IStream` implementation that takes a pointer and a size from `LoadResource`. Also `CSharedFile` is an option.

EDIT: Also the new MFC provides a `CPngBitmap` that allows to load a PNG file as a HBITMAP directly from a memory source.

Answer (score 1):

You can load an image from a hardcoded path or from a Stream. To load it from a Stream, use the following code. First, add a function for creating the stream from the resource.

```
IStream* ZDlg::CreateStreamOnResource(LPCTSTR lpName, LPCTSTR lpType)
{
    IStream * ipStream = NULL;

    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, lpName, lpType);
    if (hrsrc == NULL)
        goto Return;

    DWORD dwResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    HGLOBAL hglbImage = LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    if (hglbImage == NULL)
        goto Return;

    LPVOID pvSourceResourceData = LockResource(hglbImage);
    if (pvSourceResourceData == NULL)
        goto Return;

    HGLOBAL hgblResourceData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwResourceSize);
    if (hgblResourceData == NULL)
        goto Return;

    LPVOID pvResourceData = GlobalLock(hgblResourceData);

    if (pvResourceData == NULL)
        goto FreeData;

    CopyMemory(pvResourceData, pvSourceResourceData, dwResourceSize);

    GlobalUnlock(hgblResourceData);

    if (SUCCEEDED(CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hgblResourceData, TRUE, &ipStream)))
        goto Return;

FreeData:
    GlobalFree(hgblResourceData);

Return:
    return ipStream;
}
```

Then use the function as follow:

```
pImage = new CImage;
IStream *pStream = CreateStreamOnResource(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MYIMAGE), _T("PNG"));
if (pStream != nullptr)
{
    pImage->Load(pStream);
    pImage->SetHasAlphaChannel(true);
    pStream->Release();
}
```